# Is it possible to use the same table twice in an update statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm trying to write a query along these lines:

```
UPDATE Table i2
SET value = 0
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table i1 WHERE i2.ID = i1.ID+1)
```

The problem is that I'm getting "Incorrect syntax near 'i2'."  I'm guessing this is because it doesn't like giving a nickname to a table being updated, but if that's the case, how am I supposed to reference it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An update does not only have to be on a table directly you can use an alias from a table referenced in the `From` clause.

```
UPDATE i2
SET value = 0
FROM Table i2
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table i1 WHERE i2.ID = i1.ID+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The "value" within the "SET" clause is a keyword of SQL.Further, your logic seems to be clearing all the "value"s except the first row, is it your goal?

Comment: This is a simplification of that actual query.  "value" was a column.  There were also extra constraints that made it "everything except the first in each set".